# GetLimitedWebPartManager on published version of file (not latest checked in)

Tags: versioning, version-history

This is SharePoint 2010.
I want to get the published web parts from a page that have three versions.
When I call the GetLimitedWebPartManager() on the version that I want I get 0x80070003
This error I have only gotten when working with restore-spsite and google do not seem to have seen this before.
Anyone that knows of a way to from code get the webparts of an older version of a SPFile?

Full code of consol app

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://portal/sites/Clone3/"))
            {
                SPWebCollection sites = siteCollection.AllWebs;
                foreach (SPWeb site in sites)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SPListItem splistitem = site.GetListItem("http://portal/sites/Clone3/Pages/webpart.aspx");
                        foreach (SPFileVersion version in splistitem.File.Versions)
                        {
                            if (version.Level == SPFileLevel.Published)
                            {
                                 var manager = version.GetLimitedWebPartManager();

                                 foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart webpart in manager.WebParts)
                                 {
                                     Console.Write(webpart.Title);
                                 }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                         if (site != null)
                            site.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }

             Console.Write("Press ENTER to continue");
             Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like a bug in the SPFileVersion.GetLimitedWebPartManager method. It passes an incorrect page url to the internal method SPWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManagerInternal. Unfortunately, the only work-around to this problem is currently to use reflection to call that internal method with the correct page url. The following code sample will get you a working instance of the SPLimitedWebPartManager object.

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web; 
SPLimitedWebPartManager lwpm = null;
try {
    SPFileVersion fileVersion = ...;   // Get the file version
    Type pageViewType = web.GetType().Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.PageView");
    Type[] parameterTypes = new [] { 
        typeof(Uri), 
        typeof(int), 
        pageViewType, 
        typeof(bool), 
        typeof(bool) 
    };
    MethodInfo method = web.GetType().GetMethod("GetLimitedWebPartManagerInternal", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, Type.DefaultBinder, parameterTypes, null);
    object[] parameters = new [] {
        new Uri(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(web.Url, fileVersion.File.Url)),
        fileVersion.ID,
        Enum.ToObject(pageViewType, 0),
        true,
        true
    };
    lwpm = (SPLimitedWebPartManager)method.Invoke(web, parameters);

    // Do your work with the manager here
}
finally {
    if (lwpm != null) {
        if (lwpm.Web != null) {
            lwpm.Web.Dispose();
        }
        lwpm.Dispose();
    } 
}
```

However, please note that this practice of reflecting the SharePoint API is not recommended nor is it supported.

Comment: +1.
Thanks a lot for a solution.
Have you really debugged MS code in VS to come up with understanding that it passes an incorrect page url? :)

Comment: is there anything similar for SharePoint online?